# Recover Previous Computer Names

Tags: windows-7, computer-name

Does your computer store a list of all computer names it has had?  For example, let's say your computer name is changed each reboot, would your computer somewhere have a list of all the previous computer names it has had?

Comment: If you *want* to keep a record, whatever script/program is changing the name can keep a log

Comment: Hmmm...why would the computer be changing names can you elaborate a  little more on this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only find the last name of the computer, a list is not possible. Open the **Registry Editor** and navigate to the address:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\OldName
```

[Source](http://forensicartifacts.com/2010/08/computer-name/)

Comment: I'm sure there's a log file (like in XP) that shows name changes...?

Comment: @BigChris If there is, I have not been able to find it. :)

Comment: C:\Windows\debug\NetSetup.log ? It won't just show computer names because it's a log of the domain join process. No guarantee a full list, though. I've never needed to know so I only know it's "one" way of getting a hostname from a dead pc

Comment: @BigChris In Windows 7 not exists that file. I have not found..

Comment: Ah, probably because the computer hasn't joined a domain. I think you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: @BigChris  “( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)”

Comment: It was mere curiosity - no big deal or loss on it.

Comment: This key does not hold the correct value on more recent Windows versions.  The Event Viewer method works.

Answer (score 8):

If the computer changed name recently, you can find it in the event viewer in Security, filter eventid 4648 . Then you can chose the date, and you will see what was the computer name at that time.

Comment: Hah - I knew there had to be a way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

This should search security log for your previous computer names that do not match your current one:

```
$SecLog=get-eventlog security -InstanceID 4648 | where {$_.MachineName -notlike "$Env:Computername"}
```

Then you can use that first variable to give you the whole list (probably lots of duplicates)

```
$AlloldNames=$SecLog.MachineName
```

This one will give you just the most recent old name that does not match your current one:

```
$MostRecentOldName=$SecLog.MachineName[0]
```